# slide content when click in the menu

Tags: jquery, css

i want only a simple website menu in the left side when clicking one of the link's content in the right side will slide left.

working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/2DY8M/3/)

html

```
<div class="contentLeft">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="selectBox" href="#">sample</a></li>
            <li><a class="selectBox" href="#">sample1</a></li>
            <li><a class="selectBox" href="#">sample2</a></li>
        </ul>    

    </div>

<div class="contentRight">
    <div class="selectBoxContent">its</div>
    <div class="selectBoxContent">my</div>
    <div class="selectBoxContent">way</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(function() {

            $('.selectBox').click(function() {
         $('.selectBoxContent').slideLeft('fast');
        return false;

    });
        });
```

css

```
.contentLeft {
    border:1px solid green;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
}

.contentRight {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:64%; 
    float:right;
    height:400px;
}
.selectBoxContent {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe slideLeft is part of jQuery. slideDown works just fine. Maybe you can do something with slideToggle?

Comment: thak's for the reply @tas I'm not sure also with my `jquery` code also, it this posible using only a simple jquery when clicking one of the menu the content will slide left?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14996084/1516616), hopefully it will be your answer.

Comment: hi @A.K i mean is when i click the one link in the menu one `div` will slide like transition of image by the way thank you for giving the time answering my question... thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You could use .animate rather then slide. So something like

JQuery

```
$(function() {
  $('.selectBox').click(function() {
    $('.selectBoxContent').fadeIn().animate({
      right: "0"
     }, 1000);
    return false;
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.contentRight {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:64%; 
    float:right;
    height:400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.selectBoxContent {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    display:none;
    right: -100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [jQuery UI - Slide Effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/) we can achieve this.

**jQuery**:

```
 $('.selectBoxContent').toggle( "slide" );
    return false;
 });
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2DY8M/9/)

Comment: hi it is possible that its `link` own one `div` when the `sample` link click `fist div` the only one will `slide`?